# Dagger2 provide instance of listener to injected service

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

i run into issue i am not sure how to solve..

First of all i have n services i inject into class A, and i provide class A with listener interface B, for data sharing

```
    Interface B {
        void onActionA(String a);
        void onActionB(String b);
    }

    class A {
        private B listener;

        protected @Inject C;

        protected @Inject D;

        private AppComponent component;

        A(B listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
            component = DaggerAppComponent.create();
            component.inject(this);
        }

        void onAAction() {
            listener.onActionA("a case");
        }

        void onBAction() {
            listener.onActionB("b case");
        }
    }
```

And here comes issue sometimes i need to call listener B for my class A not from class A but from injected service C or D, can i pass somehow to those injected services listener B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the overall design but yes you could pass an instance of `B` into the `AppModule` during the creation of `AppComponent` and hence make it available in the dependency tree.

Your `AppModule` will have to look something like this:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final B listener;

    public AppModule(B listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Provides
    B provideListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    @Provides
    C provideC(B listener) {
        return new C(listener);
    }

    @Provides
    D provideD(B listener) {
        return new D(listener);
    }
}
```

Then the `AppComponent` has to be created with the `AppModule` as follows:

```
public class A {
    @Inject B; // either inject or assign in constructor
    @Inject C;
    @Inject D;

    public A(B listener) {
        AppComponent component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(listener)) // now mandatory because of the non-default constructor
            .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what i need